# highcharts-angular : Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to implement highcharts-angular 
 (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) in my angular for application and getting the following error

```
Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined
at HighchartsChartComponent.updateOrCreateChart (highcharts-chart.component.ts:35)
```

I want to use bellcurve module, and I can't get it working.

I have tried to recreate my problem using stackblitz

Please see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unf7pz

Not sure what the problem is

Comment: Stackblitz url isn't working for me. But as I see in the documentation they mentioned usage as `highcharts-chart` not just `chart`.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link. Here is the right one https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgx6up

Comment: When i make the recommended change i get error Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'highcharts-chart'.

Comment: updated the post with the correct url

Comment: Did you update the code as well. Coz I don't see any change in the code. Also I see some other errors in console like `require is not a function`

Comment: I am new to stackblitz sorry. Please see if you can access this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unf7pz

Answer (score 15, accepted):

---

By using https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

---

it's easy to follow, but from your stackblitz there are some instructions you didn't follow:

1/ in `shared/Highcharts/bellcurve/bellcurve-chart.component` you need to bind Highcharts: 
  Html:

```
<highcharts-chart 
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts" --> ITS REQUIRED
  [options]="options"       --> ITS REQUIRED
```

ts:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
...
export class BellCurveChartComponent implements OnInit {
    Highcharts = Highcharts;
    options = {title: ..., xAxis: ...};
    ...
}
```

read https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#general-prerequisites

2/ you need to load the right module you want to use (bellcurve) by following the steps in https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-module

```
import bc from 'highcharts/modules/histogram-bellcurve.js';
bc(Highcharts);
```

3/ if you want to use the chart instance, use the callback Function `callbackFunction`

HTML:

```
 [callbackFunction]="getInstance.bind(this)"
```

TS:

```
 getInstance(chart): void {
    // chart instance
    this.chart = chart;
 }
```

And that's, check the working code here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k85q94

Comment: i am not confused as i am aware there are two angular wrappers. We were using angular2-highcharts earlier but now trying to use highcharts-angular highcharts as thats the official one and supported by the highcharts team. Also we have achieved all sorts of charts using  angular2-highcharts but had trouble getting the bellcurve to work. If you expand the folder structure of the project , you will find bellcurve chart component. I am trying to render that component. I think you didnt see the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unf7pz. This link uses the latest wrapper

Comment: @Tom you should explain this in your topic, I saw your old stackblitz in comments that's why I followed.  I Updated my answer with the working code, you missed some instructions

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. I missed those important steps that you mentioned. I would need one last help before I could say this migration is successful. At the moment the data is set within the highchart template. When I remove that to provide it via the component , it doesnt work. The series that I am providing is the same but what i have noticed is that this declaration in the template (load)="getInstance($event.context) is not being set. I had set this while using the angular2highchart wrapper . Is load correct ? or is it different . I couldn't find in the documentation

Comment: Please note that in order for you to try that you would have to uncomment the code in  getInstance(chartInstance) and ngOnChanges method. The ngOnchanges fires but i dont see the getinstance firing.

Comment: @Tom read the doc, you can use the callback function `[callbackFunction]="getInstance.bind(this)"` , just add bind(this) because the Default this in the function points to the chart.

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#options-details (part 4)

Comment: Perfect. Works... You have helped me a lot and i would be very thankful